# cron job two parameters - start time and end time should cover entire day

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have written a shell script for data extraction that accepts two parameters - Start time and end time in YYDDMMHHSSSS format. The shell script in turn will run sql queries and fetch data between these two date parameters.

My intention is to deploy the shell script as a cron job which should run at least once every day(preferably every 6 hours). The second time it runs it should use that last End time as the Start time, and the new End time as, say (Starttime + 6 hours). So all data is always extracted once. Another job will kick off at say 12 in the midnight everyday and it will pick up the data that the shell scrip deposited for that day.

I have never setup a cron job before but it looks doable from what I have read, I'm not sure if the above thing can be done though?

Comment: You should use [anacron(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron executes jobs at specific times and/or days with all parameters for the script defined at the time the job is placed into the cron job table. The script needs to handle all other requirements. If your requirements are based on the current time and the last time the script was executed, then the script will need to preserve the time of execution each time it is run and the obtain the last time it was invoked from the information preserved.

In this particular case, because you are accessing a database, I suggest that you use the database to preserve time of the previous script execution.

Comment: Good suggestion. Another thing that occured to me later is that it wouldn't really matter if the parameters are hard coded to 6 hour intervals, right? Shell script will always get the data for those particular intervals only. So even if the shell script for first 6 hours finishes really late, it will process data only for those 6 hours. Next time it will only process it for the next six hours. Did I just answer my own question? :)

Comment: You are correct that the shell script will only get the data for the time range specified. One thing to be aware of is that the exact  time  between executions of your script may change because of external influences such as system load and DST clock changes.